# How to get value of other table like a movies data was conected by ID in php, sql group_concat / inner join or any

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

If i have table like this

```
anime(ID,anime_name,genres,studio,series)
anime_genres(ID,anime_id,genres_id)
anime_studio(ID,anime_id,studio_id)
anime_series(ID,anime_id,series_id)
```

and

```
genres(ID,genres_name)
studio(ID,studio_name)
series(ID,series_name)
```

Problem :
How to get data like this.

```
ID | anime_name |        genres                  |      studio                | series
1  | Uq holder  | (1)action,(2)fantasy,(3)isekai |(1)A-1,(2)pierot,(3)tvtokyo | neginegima
```

i try like this

```
    SELECT anime.ID ,anime_name
     FROM anime 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT genres_id FROM anime_genres WHERE anime_id = genres ) as genre_selector
    ON genre_selector.genres = anime.genres
     INNER JOIN (SELECT genres_name FROM genres WHERE ID = genres_id) as genre_data
 ON genre_data.genres_id = anime_genres.genres_id
   ORDER BY anime.ID
```

i use this to run the query

```
$stmt = $reg_anime->animeQuery(sql statement); $stmt->execute(); while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { echo $row['ID']. ' : '. $row['anime_name']. ' '. $row['genres_name']. ' - '. $row['genres']. '<br />'; }
```

Comment: did you try any form of query yet?

Comment: wait let me edit

Comment: like that . sir

Comment: I noticed there is a PHP tag. Are you trying to do just an SQL query that produces that output, or are you wanting to format the output like that with PHP? If you're just looking for an SQL answer, how is PHP relevant? And if not, do you have any PHP code?

Comment: i use this to run the query
$stmt = $reg_anime->animeQuery();
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row['ID']. ' : '. $row['anime_name']. ' '. $row['genres_name']. ' - '. $row['genres']. '<br />';
    }

Comment: The actual table definitions and what the IDs refer to would help to solve the problem. To me it looks like the `anime_genres` and `genres` tables appear to contain duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this all in sql, though I will admit it is a bit ugly.

```
SELECT 
a.Id,
a.anime_name,
(
    STUFF((
    SELECT TOP 3 ',' + g.genres_name
    FROM 
    anime_genres ag INNER JOIN genres g
    ON ag.genres_id = g.id
    WHERE ag.anime_id = 1
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
) AS genres,
(
    STUFF((
    SELECT TOP 3 ',' + s.studio_name
    FROM 
    anime_studio as INNER JOIN studio s
    ON as.studio_id = g.id
    WHERE ag.anime_id = 1
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
) AS studio,
anime.series
FROM anime a
WHERE 
a.ID = 1
```

Comment: ty but not what i am looking for , genres and studio its to many can be 8-9 not only 3 , but ty now i have an image how could i do.

Comment: You might want to look into the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group_concat/) function, it should help group values.